# Ryan bates nested_form gem and javascript function

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, nested

I hope somebody could help me with this studid issue that is driving me nuts for the last 5 days...
Im using ryan bates brilliant nested_form gem to dynamically add and remove elements in a form everything is running smoothly.
The problem is that i now need to get the id of the new elements added to use in a document.getelementbyid kind of function...

How can I deal with this when bates gem new added lines all have the same html `id`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, you should be using a JavaScript library. I recommend jquery, which can be found [here](http://jquery.com).

Second, you can listen for the following events:

```
nested:fieldAdded
nested:fieldRemoved
```

Whenever an element is added or removed, the appropriate event is triggered. Using that you can manipulate the DOM in whatever way pleases you. Make sure you look at the gems github page for more information, [here](https://github.com/ryanb/nested_form).

Comment: Sounds interesting thanks andrew. Is there a single way to achevieve the result imlooking for. In fact i just have 3 fields 1 with quantity, second with unit price and i just want field number 3 to calculate total price (which is field 1 multiplied by field 2)

Comment: Basically you will just get field 1's value, field 2's value, multiply them, and set the result to field 3's value. You can get the value with jQuery like this: $('#field_1').val(); You can set the value with jQuery like this: $('#field_3').val(result_from_field_1_and_2);

Comment: Sounds cool again andrew but how could i get the fields id using bates gem because every new line get the same ids.... :)